# Why my query is always return to else statement even though my selected data is exist?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
$sql0unded = "SELECT * FROM tomb";
$query0unded = mysqli_query($dbconn,$sql0unded) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbconn).header("Refresh: 1,index.html"));
$row0unded = mysqli_num_rows($query0unded);
if($row0unded==1)
{ echo "yeayy";}
else
{header("Refresh:1;byebye.php");}
```

This is my database

```
CREATE TABLE `tomb` (
  `id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `ded` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tomb` (`id`, `ded`) VALUES
(1, '2019-01-01'),
(2, '2019-01-02'),
(3, '2019-01-03'),
(4, '2019-01-04'),
(5, '2019-01-05'),
(6, '2019-01-06'),
, '2019-02-10');

ALTER TABLE `tomb`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Comment: Hi! When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it. There was also a toolbar full of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area showing what your post would look like when posted, located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it). Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: I've fixed the formatting for you. Also, your question had nothing whatsoever to do with [tag:jquery], so I removed it.

Comment: Arif, as given it seems you have more than 1 one row in table `tomb` and mysqli_num_rows() returns the number of rows in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

[`mysqli_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) returns the number of results in the result set. As you insert multiple rows when setting up the table, and subsequently make a SQL query which returns *all* of those rows, the value returned from your call to `mysqli_num_rows` will be greater than 1. Accordingly, the `if` conditional test for equality to 1 fails and the `else` branch is taken.

If this is not intended behaviour, you need to:

- change the number of rows in the table so there is only one row; or
- limit the results in your `SELECT` query to ensure only one row is returned (which you should ensure is enforced using constraints in the database); or
- change your conditional to look for the value returned from the number of rows call to be `>= 1`